# Should I use NSNumber or an int in an iPhone/iPad class?

Tags: ios, integer, nsnumber

I'm creating an object that will have two integers (or `NSNumber`s) and an `NSDate` as ivars. This object will be in an `NSMutableArray`. To my knowledge, we cannot put primative integers in an `NSMutableArray`, but will my object work with `int`s? The reason I don't want to use `NSNumber`s is because these will have to be mutable, and I don't really want to create a new `NSNumber` everytime.

Also, will using `int`s create problems with iphone architecture differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can safely use ints as ivars because they are wrapped in another object. NSNumber is just a Cocoa class wrapper for the different numeric types.

2)To be safe, you could use `NSUInteger`, which is `typedef`ed like this:

```
#if __LP64__ || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

So you will get the correct type for the current architecture.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't had time to check because I think I've found a way to use NSIntegers, but I'll trust that you know what you're saying and will try integers later if NSIntegers don't work.